# How to verify an hashed password

Tags: php, password-hash

I am using the `password_hash()` function.

Now it works to hash the password, but how do I verify it?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: Who is upvoting this? Care to explain why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the function for this option is called: `password_verify`.

How it does work is this;

```
<?php
$password = "[PASS]"; //Password user fill in.
$hash= "[HASH]"; //The hashed password that you saved.
$checkPass = password_verify($password, $hash); //This returns a boolean; true or false
if ($checkPass == true)
{
  echo 'Password is good!';
}
else
{
  echo 'Password is wrong!';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean password_verify ( string $password , string $hash )
```

*Verifies that the given hash matches the given password.*

Note that `password_hash()` returns the algorithm, cost and salt as part of the returned hash. Therefore, all information that's needed to verify the hash is included in it. This allows the verify function to verify the hash without needing separate storage for the salt or algorithm information.

password
The user's password.

hash
A hash created by `password_hash()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php